# Symfony One-To-One persists a new empty row in the database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two related entities, `Variant` and `DimensionGroup`.

A `Variant` can have a `DimensionGroup`, but is not required to.

Every time I create a new `Variant`, a new `DimensionGroup` row is created in the database, with every field set to null, except for its `id`, which is auto incremental.

I want not to have the `DimensionGroup` row in the database when I persist a `Variant` that does not have a `DimensionGroup`.

The mapping looks like this:

**Variant.orm.xml**

```
<one-to-one field="dimensionGroup" target-entity="Flexy\Ftwo\Store\Entity\DimensionGroup" mapped-by="variant">
    <cascade>
        <cascade-remove/>
    </cascade>
</one-to-one>
```

**DimensionGroup.orm.xml**

```
<one-to-one field="variant" target-entity="Flexy\Ftwo\Store\Entity\Variant" inversed-by="dimensionGroup">
    <join-column name="variant_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="true" />
</one-to-one>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What does the `Variant` class look like? And can you show an example of how you instantiate it?

Comment: `$form = $this->createForm(new VariantType(), $variant = new Variant());` The `Variant` constructor does not have anything special.

Comment: I'm guessing your variantFormType includes a dimensionGroupFormType?  The form processor is basically creating the empty dimensionGroup and linking it to the variant.